# Why does the hash value of models change everytime I save it?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using torch.save() to save a model file. However, everytime I save it, it changes. Why so?

```
netG_1 = torch.load('netG.pth')
netG_2 = torch.load('netG.pth')

torch.save(netG_1, 'netG_1.pth')
torch.save(netG_2, 'netG_2.pth')
```

Using `md5sum *.pth`:

```
779f0fefca47d17a0644033f9b65e594  netG_1.pth
476f502ec2d1186c349cdeba14983d09  netG_2.pth
b0ceec8ac886a11b79f73fc04f51c6f9  netG.pth
```

The model is an instance of this class:

https://github.com/taoxugit/AttnGAN/blob/master/code/model.py#L397

Answer (score 5):

A class which does not define the `__hash__` method will have its instances hashed according to their `id`. As for CPython, this means everytime the instance is saved and reloaded, it changes hash since its position in memory changed.

Here is a proof of concept.

```
class Foo:
    pass

instance = Foo()

print('hash:', hex(hash(instance)))
print('id:  ', hex(id(instance)))
```

### Output

```
hash: 0x22f3f57608
id:   0x22f3f576080
```

The exact transformation is `hash(o) == id(o) // 16`.

Comment: ```
class Test:
    x = 5
    pass

m = Test()

pickle.dump(m, open('m.p', 'w'))

a = pickle.load(open('m.p', 'r'))
b = pickle.load(open('m.p', 'r'))

pickle.dump(a, open('a.p', 'w'))
pickle.dump(b, open('b.p', 'w'))
```

Then after doing `md5sum *.p`:
```
86cdcd4e714de83f18b519052470155f  a.p
86cdcd4e714de83f18b519052470155f  b.p
86cdcd4e714de83f18b519052470155f  m.p
```

Comment: But when I save two instances of the same class to memory, shouldn't their hash values be the same? Because their contents are the same.

Comment: @canonball Their hash value may or may not be the same. As explained, their content is irrelevant if you did not define the `__hash__` method. What matters is their position in memory, which may or may not have been the same. If you want the hash to be based on their content, define `__hash__`

Comment: I was talking about the md5sum hash value which is an indication of the contents of the file.

Comment: @canonball Oh, so you whole question has nothing to do with Python, but only with md5sum?

Comment: It has to do with python only. md5sum is a way of me telling you to check the hash value of the contents of a file once it has been dumped outside a python file. See this: https://gist.github.com/arunpatro/f109963bdec59ee08b37070b8078a9fc

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken serializing an object shouldn't depend on where the object happens to be in memory (otherwise serializing it wouldn't be useful). Torch seems to have some kind of internal state associated with the model that is saved with it. Python's implementation of the native `hash` function is not relevant to the question as @canonball is running an md5 hash on the model on disk anyway.

Comment: FYI this appears to be referenced here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/42163